# Subtraction of values based on IDs and group after

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subtraction

I'm using Oracle.

Having a table as:

```
Year   Type   Value
2011   1       500
2011   2       550
2011   3       600
...
...
2012   1       600
2012   2       750
2012   3       930
```

I need to subtract all the values from different types, grouped by year.
The operation would be:

For 2011 -> 1-2-3 (500-550-600)

For 2012 -> 1-2-3 (600-750-930)

For ...

The result should be:

```
Year   Value
2011   -650  
2012   -1080 
...    ...
```

I'm just not managing to get this query working..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when type = 1 then value else - value end) as value
from table t
group by year;
```

Comment: Much better solution (+1)!

Comment: @sgeddes . . . Your solution is quite reasonable . . . although it could be improved by having an `end` so it is syntactically correct. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You mean GROUP BY, CASE to decide sign +for type 1, - for others:

```
select "year", 
       SUM(case when type = 1 then value else -value end)
from yourtable
group by "year"
```

Comment: Oops. I'm a bit slow here... (Didn't notice Gordon Linoff's answer until now.)