# subtraction between two queries with group by

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions, mariadb-10.3

I use MariaDB and have two tables (orders, invoiced_positions) and I need to calculate how many of each item were invoiced and paid for. So I need to count the rows and group by item_name. The problem of this is that some of the items are reopened: so I need to subtract the number of reopened invoices from the ones that were not. Basically: I want to do for **all** items what I achieved here for only one item:

```
SELECT  
(SELECT COUNT(item_name = 'Streuselkuchen') 
 FROM orders, invoiced_positions 
 WHERE order_id = id AND reopened = 0)
 - (SELECT COUNT(item_name = 'Streuselkuchen') 
    FROM orders, invoiced_positions 
    WHERE order_id = id AND reopened != 0) AS Difference;
```

I think this can be achieved with a conditional aggregation as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902294/subtraction-of-values-based-on-ids-and-group-after) but I haven't been able to apply this to my specific task.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: @PeterStrawson the edits that you propose to my answer would produce invalid sql code. Use the aliases and not the full table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a proper `JOIN` of the tables, `GROUP BY item_name`, and then conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT item_name, SUM(reopened = 0) - SUM(reopened != 0) AS Difference
FROM orders AS O INNER JOIN invoiced_positions AS IP  
ON IP.order_id = O.id     
GROUP BY item_name;
```

I did not qualify the columns `item_name` and `reopened` with table aliases because it is not obvious where they belong, but you should do it.

Comment: Now it works and produces the right result. Thanks a lot!