# Subtraction of values between two values when group by is applied to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So my issue is I want to get the value of the subtraction of the secondary groups for each primary group.

I applied `groupby()` for two columns `'Country'` and `'doc_type'` and I want the subtraction of the values (`SAL-SRT`) obtained for each `Country`, using pythons pandas

```
Country      doc_type
Afghanistan  SAL         4375.0
             SRT          144.0
Algeria      SAL         8613.0
             SRT           28.0
Australia    SAL          356.0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You could improve your question by showing us the code you have tried so far and your desired results.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902318/5682238

Answer (score 1):

try `pivot()`

```
df.pivot(index='Country', columns='doc_type', values='values')
```

`reset_index()` & `fillna(0)`, then subtract:

```
df['delta'] = df.SAL - df.SRT
```